# How to use 'as.factor' with 'apply'?

Tags: r

I tried to convert the categorical features in a dataset to `factor`s. However, using `apply` with `as.factor` did not work:

```
convert <- c(2:5, 7:9,11,16:17)
read_file[,convert] <- data.frame(apply(read_file[convert], 2, as.factor))
```

However, switching to `lapply` did work:

```
read_file[,convert] <- data.frame(lapply(read_file[convert], as.factor))
```

Can someone explain to me what's the difference and why second code works while the first fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` returns a matrix and a matrix cannot contain a factor variable. Factor variables are coerced to character variables if you create a matrix from them. The documentation in `help("apply")` says:

> In all cases the result is coerced by `as.vector` to one of the basic
> vector types before the dimensions are set, so that (for example)
> factor results will be coerced to a character array.

`lapply` returns a list and a list can contain (almost) anything. In fact, a data.frame is just a list with some additional attributes. You don't even need to call `data.frame` there. You can just subset-assign a list into a data.frame.